# How to make python pop up window stay on top

Tags: python

In python, we can create a pop window by define

```
def pop(msg):
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
    MessageBox(None, msg, 'Window title', 0)
```

then

```
pop('some message')
```

will give a pop up window to notify users.

But how to make this pop up window on top of all other windows, so users can absolutely not miss it?

Comment: `MessageBox(None, msg, 'Window title', 0x40000)` ?

Comment: @kabanus Thank you so much

Comment: @DirtyBit Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
MessageBox(None, msg, 'Window title', 0x40000)
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd probably be a better idea to use tkinter - in addition for it being part of python, it's also cross platform.

Here's an example pop up:

```
from tkinter import messagebox, Toplevel, Label, Tk, Button


def pop(msg):  # This will be on top of the window which called this pop up
    messagebox.showinfo('message', msg)


def pop_always_on_top(msg):  # This will be on top of any other window
    msg_window = Toplevel()
    msg_window.title("Show Message")
    msg_window.attributes('-topmost', True)
    msg_label = Label(msg_window, text=msg)
    msg_label.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    button = Button(msg_window, text="Ok", command=msg_window.destroy)
    button.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    top = Tk()

    hello_btn = Button(top, text="Say Hello", command=lambda: pop('hello world!'))
    hello_btn.pack()
    hello_btn = Button(top, text="Say Hello and stay on top!", command=lambda: pop_always_on_top('hello world - on top!'))
    hello_btn.pack()
    top.mainloop()
```

The message box is automatically on top of its parent window.

If you want to make it on top of every other window on the system, set the '-topmost' flag of your window (as the second method demonstrates).

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems that your function has some problem. The popup windows always stopped working

Comment: What do you mean by stopped working?

Comment: when I want to close the pop up window, it just freeze

Comment: Weird.. it doesn't happen when I test it.. what python version and OS are you using? Maybe it's a bug in the framework...